# How to prove $\sup(f(x)^2) = (\sup(f(x)))^2$

Tags: functions, supremum-and-infimum

I started the proof with this:

$$\sup(f(x)^2) = \sup(f(x)*f(x)) = \sup(f(x)) * \sup(f(x) = (\sup(f(x)))^2$$

But it doesn't feel right. Any ideas or comments?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f:[-10,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x$. Then $sup(f(x)^2)=100$ and $(sup(f(x)))^2=1$. They are not equal.

Comment: Thank you very much!, But what happens when $x \in \R^d$ and $f: \R^d -> \R$ ?

Comment: You can also find many counterexamples in the setup you gave. Notice that $f$ has no any special property like continuous.